Не находится команда в disnake
Возникла проблема с библиотекой disnake.
В коде я создал бота и добавил ему два события и одну команду:
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands
from CONFIG import MAIN_CHANNEL, PREFIX, TOKEN, CENSORED_WORDS

activity = disnake.Activity(
    name="за тобой",
    type=disnake.ActivityType.watching,
)

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX, help_command=None, intents=disnake.Intents.all(), activity=activity)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = bot.get_channel(MAIN_CHANNEL) #сообщает о начале работы когда запущен
    print("Начал работу")
    await channel.send("Бот запущен!") #отправляет сообщение в основной канал

@bot.event
async def on_message(message): #проверяет есть ли плохие слова в сообщении
    for content in message.content.split():
        for bad_word in CENSORED_WORDS: 
            if content == bad_word:
                await message.delete()
                await message.author.send("Не обзывайся!") #удаляет сообщение и пишет об этом в ЛС
    await bot.process_commands(message)

@bot.command
async def rnd(ctx):
    print("Команда вызвана")


bot.run(TOKEN)

Когда я запускаю файл то бот модерирует сообщения и пишет о том что он запущен но не реагирует на команду, а когда я пытаюсь выполнить команду то в командную строку выводится следующая ошибка:
Ignoring exception in command None:
disnake.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "rnd" is not found


Почему такое происходит? команда точно инициализирована. Возможно я как то не так ее инициализировал? Большое всем спасибо за помощь.

Измените:

@bot.command --> @bot.command()

